# htaccess redirect + hide subfolder in url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've looked around and have attempted some rules and conditions that worked; while some did not work or the condition would capture too much causing other domains to also redirect. This works for me:

```
# Redirect (also catches www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder [L]
```

resulting in if you visit www.domain.com OR domain.com
being redirected to domain.com/subfolder
Great, but I'dd also like the /subfolder part to be hidden from the url.

How do I achieve this ?

Note that I have multiple domains, each should redirect to its own folder.
I also want each page to still be visible in its respective folder.

So www.domain.com/abc should redirect to domain.com/subfolder/abc but show domain.com/abc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule !^subfolder/ /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

Comment: This works ! But I just noticed that the www. part is treated as optional, instead of being removed. While this is perfectly fine, is it possible to let it also always remove the www. ?

Comment: Actually we need a separate www removal rule since this is just internal rewrite.

Comment: Don't forget you need `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: @Zerreth. You typically want to allow www in the DNS settings by adding a CNAME record and then a simple redirect in .htaccess or http.conf without www

Comment: anubhava can you tell how to exclude several folders like `RewriteRule 
 !^subfolder/ OR !^subfolder2/ OR  !^subfolder3/  /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]`

Comment: @tBook: Use: `RewriteRule !^(subfolder|subfolder1|subfolder2)/ /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,NC]`