# How to put wordpress in subfolder but without changing permalinks and exchanging only homepage with static html

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I have a task for which methods used in this atricle: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory unfortunatelly wont help with.

I want to place bootstrap static HTML as homepage so adress is www.exampledomain.com

I have a wordpress I move to www.exampledomain.com/subdirectory
now I want my old wordpress homepage to be on www.exampledomain.com/subdirectory but any other pages and permalinks unchanged so not like: www.exampledomain.com/subdirectory/somepage but:
www.exampledomain.com/somepage. Everything working with static html on domain homepage.

Simply making subdirectory a WordPress Address and domain homepage as Site Address doesn't result in what I want cause old permalinks do not work.

How can I accomplish something like this? through htaccess? some plugin? Or perhaps some wordpress setting?

Comment: you don't need to go through much hassle, since apache renders html files first, and then php files (unless told otherwise). So by simply putting your **index.html** file in the wordpress root folder, the user will get treated with your custom html landing page instead of the wordpress one!

Comment: I have tried it but putting index.html without changing wordpress homepage breaks the woocommerce store. Original wordpress homepage needs to be present on some link for plugins and such to work properly. That is why I presumed wordpress needs to be moved to subfolder

Comment: Greg, I have never encountered what you are saying about plugins working improperly and woocommerce breakdown on behalf of a simple index.html file. And I am sure that no such error happens, because the index.php file is still present in the root wordpress folder, so it gets rendered and called as needed.
    from what I can tell, perhaps you deleted the index.php instead of simply putting the index.html in the same folder.    If that is not the case, perhaps you have greater issues to look into your wordpress installation, instead of focusing on html landing pages.

Comment: I have just tested it and can confirm - original index.php from wordpress instalation is present. Putting index.html without changing original wordpress homepage location will indeed cause homepage to be loaded from static html but it is also causing woocommerce ajax to fail (store doesn't add items to cart). Removing index.html or moving wordpress to subfolder fixes the issue. Problem with subfolder option remains in permalinks

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Another approach would be to hide the subfolder path in your .htaccess file. take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978869/htaccess-redirect-hide-subfolder-in-url